# php form not submitting without any erros

Tags: php, mysql

I am making this script the form action method is supposed to reference the current file in $script_name variable and data to database but its not working

rest of my code is working i tried e_all and var_dump($_POST) is array(0){}

```
<h3>Leave a comment</h3>
<form action="<?php echo $SCRIPT_NAME . '?id='. $validentry ; ?>" method="post">
<table> <tr>
  <td>Your name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Comments</td>
  <td><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td>
</tr> <tr>
<td></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Add comment"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "blog");
  $con->select_db("blog");
  $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(blog_id, dateposted,
 name, comment) VALUES(" .
    $validentry . ", NOW(), '" . $_POST['name']
 . "', '" . $_POST['comments'] . "');";
  $con->query($sql);
  header("Location: http://" . $HTTP_HOST
 . $SCRIPT_NAME . "?id=" . $validentry);
}
else {
  echo "not posted any results into comment box";
}
```

it should submit form and show data on same page

Comment: Just so you know `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {` is more simply written as `if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {`.  And you are mixing procedural with object-oriented mysqli syntax.  You are not using prepared statements with bound params, so your query is not safe or stable.

Comment: I changed it but it still not solving issue of sending form data to database and  stays at the same page

Comment: Correct, I am identifying addition problems with your code.

Comment: Could you please look into why this form is not working its really urgent I have been playing around with it since last 2 days but no luck

Comment: Do you have the required HTML tags like html, body, head etc. to make this valid?

Comment: yes i have all html head body and everything

Comment: In your form you have comment and in the code you have comments. This should have given an error if error reporting was on.

Comment: what does `<?php echo $SCRIPT_NAME . '?id='. $validentry ; ?>` resolve to?

Comment: I don't see where `$SCRIPT_NAME`, `$HTTP_HOST`, and `$validentry` are declared.  Why are you nominating `blog` as the database twice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56954798/4761118 
this is complete script $$con is solved already in my real code

Comment: ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', true);
its all on and i changed comments to comment in but its not working Sorry about some silly mistakes I am very new to this

Comment: We can only review what you have posted here.

Comment: yes I know I cant post full script here i already posted it earlier I just added that link for reference of full code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, your original code, cleaned up a bit, using prepared statements as per the format provided in [the docs - bind params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Note: `blog_id = ''` - I've not used a `$validentry` in the query-string of the form-submit(deleted the action target and set it to `"#"`). Once you get this basic form submission to work - stored in the database table -, then debug how you can use `$validentry` as `blog_id`.

```
<h3>Leave a comment</h3>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Your name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comments</td>
            <td><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add comment"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "blog");

    /* check connection */
    if (!$conn) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO comments (blog_id, dateposted, name, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $blog_id, $dateposted, $name, $comment);

    $blog_id = '';
    $dateposted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // the MySQL DATETIME format
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    /* execute prepared statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

    /* close statement and connection */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// redirect...

}
```

If you need to check on the database / table(s) you have set up in PhpMyAdmin, select your database in the left pannel, then select the table you want to view. Hit tab 'structure' to investigate the table's columns names, types, etc.

An example: screenshot of a database called 'chat' with table 'chat' and its properties (shown under tab 'structure').
[image]

Comment: much appreciated but unfortunately still its not inserting anything into database 

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pub2/viewentry.php on line 70

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in on line 78

Warning: mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given on line 80
0 Row inserted. 
Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean  on line 83

Comment: Then we need to see your database table schema.   We don't know the correct structure.

Comment: `mysqli_prepare()` returned FALSE... there is something wrong with the query. Verify your table name `comments`, and your column names `blog_id`, `dateposted`, `name` and `comment` are correct

Comment: how to show you database scheme through php my admin

Comment: Just go to Structure and copy your fields

Comment: When you're in PhpMyAdmin select your database (left pannel shows all databases), then select the table and select the 'structure' tab to show your table structure (column names etc.)

Answer (score -1):

try to edit your query to be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    die();
    //$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "blog");
    if($con){
       //$con->select_db("blog");
      // $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(blog_id, dateposted,
       //name, comment) VALUES(" .
     // $validentry . ", NOW(), '" . $_POST['name']
    // . "', '" . $_POST['comments'] . "');";
      //mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      //mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    echo "Connection error";
}
```

}

Comment: my database table name is comments and field name is comment

Comment: Then you have to rename textarea name to `comments`, or edit `$_POST['comments]` to $_POST['comment]

Comment: I done it soon you said it but still it not working uploading any data

Comment: Like it was mentioned before by @mickmackusa You have not a good writing syntax. You have to move connection statements in if statemnet and check if `$conn` exist and after that execute query. Also in if statement of checking connection, if that return false echo some text value or throw an error with error description

Comment: And also, you do not need action in form if you submit on the same page, remove that too. Just to make sure that you do not have something else in SCRIPT global

Comment: i put $con in if statement and it returns true means connection is available but somehow still i am unable to post data into database

Comment: have you removed action from form?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on boolean on line 50
yes I removed action

Comment: I am trying to post id that i am getting from $_GET['id'| date posted from now() and name and comment

Comment: and Also write down this statement to see what data is submitted `var_dump($_POST); die();`, that will show if you get you POST data inside the script. after you establish connection.

Comment: You do not need `header("Location: http://" . $HTTP_HOST
 . $SCRIPT_NAME . "?id=" . $validentry);` method to rout you on the same page remove this too.

Comment: You do not have a posted data

Comment: removed it still same

Comment: var_dump($_POST); die(); in if statement with connection just shows array(0){} form is not holding any data for post method

Comment: I updated my answer, it looks suspicious Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on boolean on line 50

Comment: could you type in form `action=""`? and see if you get post dumped

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
and i var_dump($_POST);
 still same array(0){}

Comment: could you update you post with the script how it looks right now?

Comment: this script is just pulling data form database  (i.e entries) from blog and this is first time where in this script should post comments and names to database tables and no its not posting anydata from script to database

Comment: I asked you to post an updated statement where you get the post data. `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {.....`

Comment: if ($con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "blog")== true ) {
 echo "Connected ";
 // var_dump($_POST); die();
}
else{
 echo "false";
}


if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
 
 

  $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(blog_id, dateposted,
 name, comments) VALUES(" .
    $validentry . ", NOW(), '" . $_POST['name']
 . "', '" . $_POST['comments'] . "');";
  $conn = $con->query($sql);

}
else {
  echo "not posted any results into comment box";
}